# How to get current row control ID's in jquery while Place Cursor TextBox in gridview asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

How to get current row control ID's in jQuery while Place Cursor TextBox in GridView asp.net?

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.Text_Controls_Focus').focus(function () {

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.Text_Controls_Focus').focus(function () {
                // Need To Get ID of Current Row Of Griview  and 
                // Griview ID

                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
    modal: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, a Web control with an ID of `txtFirstName` can get rendered into an HTML element with a client-side id like `"ctl00_MainContent_txtFirstName"`. And same is true for ASP.NET GridView (`gdRows`), for example:

Suppose, there is TextBox and Label controls inside GridView.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

So when you run above code the IDs in HTML will be rendered as:

```
<input name="gdRows$ctl02$txtID" type="text" id="gdRows_ctl02_txtID" />
<span id="gdRows_ctl02_lblID"></span>
```

Now select controls of TextBox(s) and Label(s) as like this:

```
// select all Labels in GridView
$('#<%=gdRows.ClientID %>').find('span[id$="lblID"]').text('Your text.');

// select a particular Label in GridView
var $arrL = $('#<%=gdRows.ClientID %>').find('span[id$="lblID"]');
var $lbl = $arrL[0]; // finds a Label at 0 index
$($lbl).text('Your text...');

// select all TextBoxes in GridView
$('#<%=gdRows.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtID"]').val('Your value.');

// select a particular TextBox in GridView
var $arrL = $('#<%=gdRows.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtID"]');
var $txt = $arrL[0]; // finds a TextBox at 0 index
$($txt).text('Your text...');
```

Linked: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/02/find-control-in-aspnet-gridview-jquery.html

Comment: Thanks... I try some alternate solution... This solution to make simplify my logic.Thanks once again.